# Status item right click not triggering cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I want to trigger the right click on statusitem i am able to trigger left click but not right click .

```
-(void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification{

statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[statusItem setTitle:@"Coverdesk"];
[statusItem setEnabled:YES];

[statusItem setAction:@selector(handleStatusItemActions:)];
[statusItem setTarget:self];
[[MenuHandler defaultHandler].menu setDelegate:self];
[MenuHandler defaultHandler].delegate = self;
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];}


-(void)handleStatusItemActions:(id)sender{
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kUDKeyMouseClickPrefrence]) {

    NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
    if(event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseUp) {
        NSLog(@"left");
        [self showWindow];
    }
    else if(event.type == NSEventTypeRightMouseUp) {
        NSLog(@"right");
        [self showMenu];
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"main menu");

    [self showMenu];
}  }
```

Above code which i am using.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Added this line and it is working fine.

```
    [statusItem.button sendActionOn:NSEventMaskLeftMouseUp|NSEventMaskRightMouseUp];
```